# How to add edge loop parallel to an axis rather than relative to mesh

Tags: modeling

How can I add edge loop parallel to x axis rather than relative to mesh, I want to add edge loop so that it is similar to the grill in the reference image beside it, But when I try to do that blender adds edge loop relative to mesh which is slanted. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it correctly.
Would the "edge loop", being parallel to X on the slanted part, not cut through the part? Basically you want a grid going perfectly vertical/horizontal to fill the inner part? 
Maybe "knife" tool or model frame and add the grid as a second mesh part?